# How to deactivate the embedded email system in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, email, gmail, windows-mail

I have an Windows 8.1 tablet. I login into Windows with my Google Apps e-mail (read Gmail account).

It automatically picked up my e-mail creds and now is downloading e-mails to my machine.

Well, I see that these take up space. I don't use anything other then gmail web interface.
It there a way I can get rid of default e-mail client or have it not download my e-mails and not notify me?

Comment: You can always uninstall the application itself.

Comment: Which application is it? For me it's Windows Embedded Email Client. I doubt it can be uninstalled without any hacks.

Comment: Are you using an embedded version of windows because that's not a typical application on the full versions of Windows 8.1 or Windows RT

Comment: I used word "embedded" in a sense of "Build-in". I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: You can remove all Windows Store/Modern UI applications have you tried to remove the application it can always be reinstalled.  The application you want to remove is the mail application currently running/suspended

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall [the people, calendar and mail app](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/mail-calendar-and-people/64a79953-cf0b-44f9-b5c4-ee5df3a15c63) from Windows 8.1

Select on of the 3 tiles on start screen, do a rightclick/tab and select "uninstall".